# Как правильно создать расписание по дням из полей created_at и starts_at?

Tags: php, laravel, querybuilder

Друзья, интересен совет. Есть таблица `games` в БД, в которой лежат следующие поля:

```
id,category_id,starts_at
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы на выходе у меня получился массив следующего вида:

```
[
    "день 1" => [
        "категория 1" => [
            [игра1],[игра2],[игра3]
        ],
        "категория 2" => [
            [игра4],[игра5],[игра6]
        ],
    ],
    "день 2" => [
        "категория 3" => [
            [игра7],[игра8],[игра9]
        ],
        "категория 4" => [
            [игра10],[игра11],[игра12]
        ],
    ]
]
```

При этом нужно, чтобы игры были отсортированы по времени. Есть какие-нибудь мысли? Пишу на php, laravel. Дошел до:

```
$games = Game::with('category')
            ->oncoming()
            ->orderBy('category_id', 'asc')
            ->orderBy('starts_at', 'asc')
            ->get()
        ;
```

Но каким образом это разделить по дням?

Comment: Вам нужен метод groupBy() для [БД](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) или [коллекции](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby).

Comment: День 1, день 2, день n - это даты? или надо именно так и группировать (день 1, день 2, день 3 ...)?